# Google Sheets, CountIf, name matches and is within date range from another spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In another sheet I want to count how many meetings were scheduled for a rep within a date range.

My 3 columns are the date, rep, and misc data

```
=countifs(
"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q87c_0rFdt8FcWtIzD0KVW3k1ZpuvhfeWb1281MEs”,
”DEMOS!A2:C1000",
B2:B="Rep1",
A:A,">=11/9/2019",
A:A,"<=11/15/2019")
```

I'm a bit off it seems and I keep going around in circles.

Here is an example. I only want to count if Dates are between 11/9 and 11/15 and if the Rep is Rep1

```
A         |B
-------------------
Date      | Rep
-------------------
11/8      | Rep1
11/9      | Rep2
11/14     | Rep2
11/15     | Rep1
```

Comment: How do I combine these "=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$16, ">=11/09/2019", $A$2:$A$16,"<=11/15/2019",)"
"=COUNTIFS(B2:B1000, "Rep!") "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [COUNTIF but when multiple conditions are met](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40078/countif-but-when-multiple-conditions-are-met) + try to use `=Importrange()` because you can't import data from another spreadsheet like this. 
You can also share some sample data.

Comment: I've tried this and am now getting an error that the arguments must be in pairs 
=COUNTIFS("1q87c_0rFdt8FcWtIzD0KVW3k1ZpuvhfeWbJou1MEs","Demos!A2:A1000","=>11/09/2019","1q87c_0rFdt8FcWtIzD0KVW3k1ZpuvhfeWbJou1MEs","Demos!A2:A1000","=<11/15/2019","1q87c_0rFdt8FcWtIzD0KVW3k1ZpuvhfeWbJou1MEs","Demos!B2:B1000","Rep1")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it all in one cell you need to use Query:

```
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q87c_0rFdt8FcWtIzD0KVW3k1ZpuvhfeWb1281MEs","DEMOS!A2:C1000"),"select count(Col1) where Col2 = 'Rep1' and Col1 >= Date '2019-11-9' and Col1 <= Date '2019-11-15' label count(Col1) ''")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  That does import the data, however I was looking for a count of all of the instances that meet that criteria, any suggestions?

Comment: @MatthewD updated answer, instead of selecting * you just select count(Col1) I also added a blank label to the end to remove the header so now the formula is just returning a count. Please let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: Amazing!  It worked perfectly.  I would have never gotten there, thank you so much for you help!! @CodeCamper

Comment: I did, but I'm new so it doesn't show publicly